# Passing where expression for nhibernate query

Tags: vb.net, nhibernate

I need to give nhibernate where expression as a function parameter:

```
Public Function FindByCriteria(customCriteria As Expression(Of Func(Of Transaction, Boolean))) As IList(Of Transaction)
Dim query = GetBasicQuery()
query = query.Where(customCriteria)

return query.ToList()
End Function
```

Method is called by setting address of function inside lambda expression, because expressions doesn't support multiline in VB.NET

```
Public Sub SearchService(criteria As SearchCriteria)

_transactionService.FindByCriteria(Function(x) BuildCustomCriteriaForCustomer(x, criteria)) 
...
End Sub
```

Then inside BuildCustomCriteriaForCustomer I'm using x and criteria.

However this doesn't seem to work, it just throws NotSupportedException without any details.

Is it possible to give expressions outside of function scope?

Comment: Looks a lot like the "abstract the ORM Anti-Pattern" to me. Why not creating a `Public Function FindBySearchCriteria(customCriteria As SearchCriteria) As IList(Of Transaction)` in your transactionService?

Comment: customCriteria contains two fields which are very customer specific and I dont want to pollute my search service with customer specific fields.

Answer (score 2):

You have to build a valid expression tree which can be translated to sql. Your function `BuildCustomCriteriaForCustomer` is not translatable to sql. So this function has to convert the SearchCriteria to an Expression tree.

I assume your `SearchCriteria` is a model with property names and enums. It would be much easier to use `NhibernateSession.CreateCriteria()` and create `ICriterion` objects out of your SearchCriteria to add to it.

Comment: Yes SearchCriteria is model with property names and enums. I will try that CreateCriteria() approach and if I get it working I will post some code and approve this answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly fine to build dynamic Linq queries for use with `Session.Query()` but you can't expect NHibernate to understand the compiled code of `BuildCustomCriteriaForCustomer()`. You have to make sure the *entire* critera is a LINQ expression.

The code you have shown is equivalent to:

```
Dim query = GetBasicQuery()
query = query.Where(Function(x) BuildCustomCriteriaForCustomer(x, criteria))
```

Which of course doesn't work, because NHibernate doesn't know what `BuildCustomCriteriaForCustomer()` does (NHibernate can be extended with that knowledge, but wouldn't help in this situation.

Instead, do:

```
Public Function BuildCustomCriteriaForCustomer(criteria As SearchCriteria)
    As Expression(Of Func(Of Transaction, Boolean))

Dim f as Expression(Of Func(Of Transaction, Boolean))
x = Function (x as Customer)
        something
    EndFunction

return x
EndFunction
```

This will make the compiler preserve your LINQ expression in a format that NHibernate can analyze.

Also, [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) is useful to add a dynamic number of "and" and "or" to a LINQ expression.